# How to resize image in pub package "flutter_native_splash"?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter_native_splash 1.3.1 package to add splash screen to the app. I have two questions here.

Q1. The image size is getting displayed bigger than the desired size on the splash screen. What is right approach to decrease the size of the image on the splash screen?

Q2. How to add text below the image on the splash screen as shown in figma file below?

figma file(desired size)
[image]

app screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Q2: You can import the logo and the text together with the export.